# Add validation to Angular material disabled field

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, disabled-input

The simplified scenario is whereby on my form I have two fields - A and B.

Field A is required and enabled. 
Field B is also required but disabled and only populated (dynamically) as a result of data keyed in field A, ad as it happens in certain cases B may be resolved as NULL.

The user should not be able to submit the form unless both fields are populated, therefore I need to add required validation to field B (disabled/dynamically populated).

While the required validation works fine for enabled fields it seems ignored for the fields that are disabled.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input name="FieldA" matInput formControlName="FieldA" placeholder="Field A" [maxLength]="6">
  <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.FieldA">{{ formErrors.FieldA }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input name="FieldB" matInput formControlName="FieldB" placeholder="Field B">
  <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.FieldB">{{ formErrors.FieldB }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>


buildForm() {
  this.form = this.form.group({
      FieldA: ['', [Validators.required]],
      FieldB: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
  });
```

Is there any way I can add validation to FieldB in HTML without enabling it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522845/angular-5-validating-disabled-fields?noredirect=1#comment95849776_54522845 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `disabled` use `readonly`. The difference between these two attributes are that `disabled` fields are ignored on form submit and `readonly` fields are included on submit. Unfortunatelly angular does not support readonly option while using Reactive Forms Approach, but you can easily do it using property binding:

`<input type="text" formContolName="FieldB" [readonly]="isReadonly">`

Another option is to enable this field programmatically on submitting function (before the submit call).

EDIT:
You can also get values which are marked as a disabled controls by calling this.form.getRawValue();

From the source code comment:

> /**
>   * The aggregate value of the `FormGroup`, including any
>   disabled controls.
>   *
>   * If you'd like to include all values
>   regardless of disabled status, use this method.
>   * Otherwise, the `value` property is the best way to get the value of the group.
>   */
>
> getRawValue(): any;

Comment: [readonly] = "true" always triggers validation, even if the field has been populated with data...

Comment: If you will add `[readonly]="true"` and the fieldB will have `Validation.Required` it will validate the field on form submit as you expect

Comment: Problem is that with the following setup: 
...
FieldB: ['', [Validators.required]],
...
<input  class="disabled-font" name="FieldB" matInput formControlName="FieldB" placeholder="Field B" [value]="address" [readonly]="true">
 <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.FieldB">{{ formErrors.FieldB }}</mat-error>
...the validation is ALWAYS triggered and showing field required, even if the field is populated... Is this a bug?

Comment: What is `formErrors`? This is your own class? How do you check if the FieldB is valid? I mean how do you assign a value to `formErrors.FieldB`?

Comment: formErrors = {
  FieldA: '',
  FieldB: ''
 };

this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
   this.formErrors = this.formValidationService.validateForm(this.form, this.formErrors, true);
});

[value]="address" comes is assigned in typescript as a result of the webAPI called when fieldA is populated.

Comment: And are you sure that this webAPI call returns correct value for FieldB ?

Comment: Absolutely. I see the field being populated with a value. It is read only so that's good, except it is showing in red and validation error is thrown and I cannot proceed.Thanks for looking in this BTW!

Comment: Is is really strange, because disabled inputs are considered as invalid inputs but readonly inputs are not. `formErrors.FieldB` should be false...

Comment: Got this working. Went for [readonly] = "true" as you suggested but then had to additionally set the field's value programmatically: this.form.get('FieldB').setValue(this.result); rather than just binding it in html to a string from the code behind: [value]="address" It works now, thanks

Comment: Please fix wrong "formContolName" (missing "r") to be "formControlName". Edit queue was full, so I couldn't do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Plase use 
And make custom css

`<mat-hint class="deep-red" *ngIf="form.submitted && *ngIf="formErrors.FieldB">This field is required</mat-hint>`