# How to make a Disabled Input also Required with Angular Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validator

I have an input which will be populated when the user clicks on a dialog. So for this I had to make it disabled, because I don't want the user to manually input the value.
The only problem is that this input must be required, and I couldn't make it so far.

I have tried to add 'required' directive in the input and also tried adding Validator.required on the form creation, but none of these made the field required for the form.

```
createUnityForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        id      : [this.unity.id],
        description: [this.unity.description],
        floor: [{value: this.unity.floor, disabled: true}, Validators.required]
    });
}

<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" class="mr-16" fxFlex>
    <mat-label>{{'UNITY.FLOOR' | translate}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="{{'UNITY.SELECT-FLOOR' | translate}}"
        name="floor"
        formControlName="floor"
        required>
</mat-form-field>

<button *ngIf="action === 'edit'"
    mat-button
    class="save-button"
    (click)="matDialogRef.close(['save',unityForm])"
    [disabled]="unityForm.invalid"
    aria-label="save">
        {{'GENERAL.SAVE' | translate}}
</button>
```

unityForm is valid even when there's nothing in the input

Comment: When I try to add [disabled] = true in the input, angular shows in the console:

It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
       
      Example: 
      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
      });

Which is exactly what I coded. Doesn't work

Comment: Maybe `this.unity.floor` contains a value in the beginning. If it has value, then validation may pass

Comment: It does not.. tried with floor: [{value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required] as well and the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a `FormControl` to `disabled` its validators will be ignored.

More info: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled

Comment: This isn't right, you can't set a formControl dynamically using the disabled property, it's read only! You'll probably want Validation rules then use a readonly property to disable it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533202/add-validation-to-angular-material-disabled-field

Answer (score 6):

Try `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Answer (score 2):

When it sets the disabled attribute, the validators will be ignored.

> Disabled controls are exempt from validation checks and are not included in the aggregate value of their ancestor controls.

*See: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled*

**If you want to make it disabled with the required or consider the validation, you have to make it `readonly`.**

```js
this._formBuilder.group({
    ...
    name: ['Your value here', Validators.required]
});
```

```html
<input formControlName="name" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Radoslaw has it. Try readonly *in the HTML* instead of disabled *in the model*. This provides a similar UI to a disabling a control in the model but the validation remains operative. This can be useful (for example pulling in records from elsewhere to commit to another db, not allowing any user changes, but only committing if original data are valid)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, reactive forms don't use validators on disabled fields.
I think it's a good way to do like this:

-HTML

```
<input
type="text"
formControlName="controlName"
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': 
(c.controlName.errors || c.controlName.disabled) 
&& submited }"/>
```

-TypeScript

```
submited = false;

form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    controlName: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required]
});

get c(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;
}

save(): void {
    this.submited = true;    
    if (this.form.invalid
       || this.formControl.controlname.value === '') {
     return;
}
```

-CSS

```
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #dc3545;
}
```

When you click on button for SAVE, required field will get red border if there is no value